# C# - automatic delegate type from method

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, invoke

Any way to avoid explicitly declaring `MyMethodDelegate` in a scenario like this?

```
bool MyMethod(string x)
{
    //...
}

BeginInvoke(new MyMethodDelegate(MyMethod), x);
```

I know about lambdas a-la `()=>MyMethod(x)`, however I want to avoid them sometimes as they break edit-and-continue.

**Edit**: just `BeginInvoke(MyMethod, x)` does not work:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, params object[])' has some invalid arguments
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Delegate'
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'object[]'
```

BeginInvoke is defined as follows:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, params object[] args);
```

It does not specify any specific delegate type, so the compiler cannot detect which delegate type to instantiate from `BeginInvoke(MyMethod. x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For framework >= 3.5 you can use predefined delegates Action<> and Func<> (in your case)

```
    BeginInvoke(new Func<int, bool>(MyMethod), x);
```

Docs for Func
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549151.aspx

Comment: Beat me to it. Although the `int` should be a `string` as per the OP.

Answer (score 3):

You can often use the simplified version

```
MyMethod
```

when a delegate is required. the keyword is **often**.

However if the compiler can't determine which type of delegate to convert the method group to you will have to help out with an explicit conversion

Lambdas can come in handy when you wish to pass a function that you haven't already defined and don't need at other locations in the code. Then Lambdas (and anonymous functions in general) will be very handy since you can then simply define the function at the spot where you need it.

in the case of BeginInvoke you are correct as noted in the comments that you can't you will need to explicitly convert the method group to a delegate either by casting or by assignment

```
Func<int,bool) m = MyMethod;
BeginInvoke(m,x);
BeginInvoke((Func<inte,bool>)MyMethod,x);
```

will compile or you can pass in a lambda because that's interpreted as a Func

```
BeginInvoke(a=>MyMethod(a),x);
```

Comment: does not work, as BeginInvoke() expects a generic delegate. updated post.

Comment: @IvanShcherbakov you've written that you can't pass MyMethod as a delegate that takes __no__ arguments which is true because MyMethod takes one. It's a long time since I've written "BeginInvoke" but would expect it to work if you actually pass an argument

Comment: I have left it out here for simplicity. I have obviously passed it in the actual code.

Comment: @Ivan there's nothing obciously about you doing something different from what you state you actually did :)

Comment: OK, sorry. I assumed that it's obvious that the problem is in conversion from MyMethod to delegate and not in the following 'params object[] args`. Nonetheless, it does not work.

Comment: @IvanShcherbakov the error message you've posted explicitly states that the **2** argument can't be cponverted to the expected type (as well as the first argument)

Comment: OK, I agree, that was a bit confusing. Nonetheless, just BeginInvoke(MyMethod, x) does not work (I have double-checked that the argument types are matching).